# How to determine which thread is created from another?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, multithreading, parent-child, chaining

Is there any way in .NET for a thread to determine its 'parent', i.e. the thread that created it?

I'm diagnosing a timing issue with a black box third party API and would like to find out what custom code of mine it is executing on which thread.

Answer (score 0):

Kindof
If you use a tool like PostSharp (you have to implement an aspect), you can determine on which threads the Start() method was called.